# Calendar.getInstance()... basic question

Tags: java, calendar

Does `Calendar.getInstance(`) work like a regular singleton in the sense that if I've called  `getInstance` somewhere else and set the day, month, etc then if I call `Calendar.getInstance()` somewhere else those fields will be set to whatever I set them before? In other words, if I want the `Calendar.getInstance()` to return a `Calendar` object with the current time and day, etc, what do I need to do? Just call `clear()`? Does that reset the instance to the current time, etc?

My apologies if this is a stupid question.

Comment: Try it and see what happens. All you have to do is get an instance and display the object. Then you can sleep for a few seconds. Then you get the instance again and display the value and see if they are the same or different.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

No, `Calendar.getInstance()` is not returning a singleton instance.  The point of using `getInstance()` is that it will take the default locale and time-zone into account when deciding which Calendar implementation to return and how to initialize it.

So you don't need to do anything to get a second Calendar with the current time, just call `Calendar.getInstance()` again.

Comment: @camickr Learning how to use the API documentation is a valuable skill, but I do not think aroth deserves a downvote for helping someone...

Comment: It doesn't help the poster learn how to problem solve. People need to learn how to read the API.

Comment: I wish more people would downvote. We would be doing the poster a favour by teaching them how to rely on themselves to do some basic problem solving BEFORE posting a question on the forums. And don't worry there will be plenty of people who give you a sympathy upvote anyway.

Comment: @camickr - Asking your question in a public forum dedicated to the subject is a valid form of problem-solving.  Maybe it's not as independent and self-reliant as you would prefer, but if LuxuryMode chooses to ask his question here, and people such as myself and KyleM willingly choose to answer, then what is the big deal?

Comment: You are the one making a big deal of it. You where free to answer, I was free to downvote. I gave a reason for my downvate (which is more than most people do on the forum). You either agree or disagree with my reasons.

Comment: I did sort of realize after I posted that this was simple enough to find out myself. My apologies and thanks @aroth for answering. I see now that `clear()` will set me back to January 1st, 1970, which is not what I want obviously ;) Thanks again.

Comment: @aroth why does Calendar.getInstance().equals(Calendar.getInstance()) return true and why do they both have the same hashcode ?

Comment: @bluelurker - The [source-code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Calendar.java#Calendar.equals%28java.lang.Object%29) is informative.  The `Calendar` class provides its own implementations of `equals()` and `hashCode()` that treat two instances that refer the same moment in time as 'equal'.  That's not the same thing as a singleton.  If a singleton were being used, then `Calendar.getInstance() == Calendar.getInstance()` would evaluate to `true`.  If you try it, you'll find that statement evaluates to `false`.

Answer (score 13):

Generally you can use the API documentation (see source) for questions like this. From the API documentation:

> Calendar's getInstance method returns a Calendar object whose calendar
>   fields have been initialized with the current date and time:
>
> ```
>      Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
> ```

Source:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: @camickr: KyleM gave a perfect example showing how the API documentation is useful. Don't you think that's helpful in teaching why you should consult the API documentation?

Comment: @camickr Who cares? You're the StackOverflow police am I right? OP asked a question and I was nice enough to give the answer. Maybe the OP will use the API doc next time now that (s)he sees that's where I got my info from.

Comment: No because now the poster doesn't actually have to read the API.  If the poster reads the API they will find that exact statement, so there is no need to repost it here. Also, while they are reading the API they many notice some other helpful method that they can use in the future.